# Incomplete and Intransitive Preferences: Reference Request

Tags: microeconomics, reference-request

I've had the opportunity to read this blog post on incomplete and intransitive preferences and would like to cite it in a informal presentation. However I cant seem to find the author.

The main site seems extremely old, though I find this essay extremely insightful for someone at my level any guidance for who the author is appreciated.

The site link: https://cruel.org/econthought/essays/get/intransitive.html

Comment: The administrator(s) of the site [says](https://cruel.org/econthought/references.html): "*Most of the writings on the individual economists webpages, Schools of Thought, and under "Essays and Surveys" were composed by ourselves (mostly  ​Gonçalo Fonseca). As this commentary is always changing, we do not encourage citation or reference to this material.*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [contact page](https://cruel.org/econthought/contact.html) my guess would be [​Gonçalo Fonseca](https://www.ineteconomics.org/research/experts/gfonseca), whose research focuses on the intersection of the history of economic thought and economic theory, or/and [Leanne Ussher](https://sites.google.com/site/leanneussher/). You can probably drop them an email (there is an email contact).